# Can KVM run on top of host OS?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization, xen, linux-kvm

I was interested in experimenting with Xen until I discovered that it *has* to be installed bare metal. Hence, if I have a Linux machine and want to use it to run a Xen hypervisor, I have to install the Xen server/kernel on the machine bare metal, and turn my host Linux into a VM of the Xen server!

I have used VirtualBox a lot before, where VBox sits "on top" of my host OS, allowing me to keep my Linux/Windows/whatever host, and run the hypervisor off of it.

I am wondering: which department does KVM fall into? Is KVM like Xen, where I have to install it bare metal, or can it be installed "on top of" an existing host (Windows/Linux) OS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please do at least some basic research.

The [Wikipedia article on KVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel-based_Virtual_Machine) says that it is implemented as a Linux kernel module (and later ported to Illumos), thus mostly type-2 like VirtualBox. But since KVM comes as a standard part of the OS, you could also say it's right in the middle.

(However, you still need to install the user-space tools (`qemu -enable-kvm`) to use it on Linux.)

---

Or, as the [hypervisor classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervisor) page says,

> … the distinction between these two types is not necessarily clear. Linux's Kernel-based Virtual Machine (KVM) and FreeBSD's bhyve are kernel modules that effectively convert the host operating system to a type-1 hypervisor.
>
> Nevertheless, since Linux distributions and FreeBSD are still general-purpose operating systems, with other applications competing for VM resources, KVM and bhyve can also be categorized as type-2 hypervisors.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @grawity (+1) - I did not realize KVM was specific to Linux. A quick followup if you don't mind: if Macs are based on FreeBSD, then is KVM available to Macs as a hypervisor option?

Comment: @smeeb: No. FreeBSD only implemented bhyve (its KVM equivalent) in 2014. While the OS X kernel (but not Mac OS) does have bits and pieces of FreeBSD, they're at least a decade older than that. You could use [Parallels](http://lifehacker.com/5861391/the-best-virtualization-app-for-mac-os-x) or VirtualBox on OS X, though.

Comment: Thanks @grawity (+1 again), do you mean that I could use VirtualBox (which I'm familiar with) to spin upa KVM hypervisor, is that what you're implying?

Comment: I'm saying that VirtualBox is _a_ hypervisor; it does not use KVM though, and OS X doesn't have KVM.